# LinkedIn Login Screen Timeout on Mobile Browser

Tags: linkedin-api

Our Native app relies on LinkedIn OAuth2 for authentication. How it works is we redirect user from our Native app to Mobile Browser (Mobile Safari or Android native browser, NOT webview) for LinkedIn authentication. Everything looks fine, but once in a while, maybe 1/10 times, the LinkedIn authentication page will be timeout and a blank page will be shown. Do you know what is causing that? Below is the sample url that the app loads on Mobile Browser.

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?approval_prompt=force&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress&redirect_uri=https://XXXXXXXXXXX.com/linkedinCallback.html&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXXXX&state=XXXXXXX

Comment: Same issue here... lot's of timeouts. I'm using an updated fork of  https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

Comment: @Ken Goo: The /authorization redirect URL looks fine. When the authentication dialog does times out, any chance you could provide from your logs the HTTP response you get back from LinkedIn? That'll help determine the root cause.

Also, if you're building a native mobile app I highly suggest you use the LinkedIn mobile SDK to handle auth. It's a much better experience for your users and it's also easier to develop with than relying on the web auth flow. Since you're building on Android: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kamyar Mohager, I switched to the new, native Linkedin SDK. So far, it isn't plagued by the same timeout / blank page issues as the web auth flow.